# I am a Strong Believer of Allah SWT. But Why a Non-Believer of Allah SWT gets his things

Tags: allah, non-muslim, debt, helping

This question still breaking my head. I am suffering from financial issues. I am seeking help from Allah SWT past 3 years through Salah, Dua and Dikhr. I had asked few friends, but still my debts are not gone.

But a non-believer who suffers from debt or financial problems, pray and seek help from other creatures and statues ( I don't want to call it as God) and they get the financial help and they happily pray to the same for other needs.

So, what's the point here? If there is no God Except Allah SWT and Allah SWT is the Only One responsible for everything, how a Non-Believer is getting everything.

Even at this very moment, I haven't reduced even a little bit of hope and believe in my Rab Allah SWT. Please provide me some views on it.

Comment: See also:  http://quran.com/35/5, http://quran.com/42/30 and http://quran.com/20/131

Answer (score 3):

*المومن کالجبل راسخ لا تحرکه العواصف*

A believer is like mountain, the winds cannot move him!

*عَنِ الصَّادِقِ جَعْفَرِ بْنِ مُحَمَّدٍ ع أَنَّهُ قَالَ: إِنَّ الْعَبْدَ إِذَا كَثُرَتْ ذُنُوبُهُ وَ لَمْ يَجِدْ مَا يُكَفِّرُهَا بِهِ ابْتَلَاهُ اللَّهُ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ بِالْحُزْنِ فِي الدُّنْيَا لِيُكَفِّرَهَا فَإِنْ فَعَلَ ذَلِكَ بِهِ وَ إِلَّا أَسْقَمَ بَدَنَهُ لِيُكَفِّرَهَا بِهِ فَإِنْ فَعَلَ ذَلِكَ بِهِ وَ إِلَّا شَدَّدَ عَلَيْهِ عِنْدَ مَوْتِهِ لِيُكَفِّرَهَا بِهِ فَإِنْ فَعَلَ ذَلِكَ بِهِ وَ إِلَّا عَذَّبَهُ فِي قَبْرِهِ لِيَلْقَى اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ يَوْمَ يَلْقَاهُ وَ لَيْسَ شَيْ‏ءٌ يَشْهَدُ عَلَيْهِ بِشَيْ‏ءٍ مِنْ ذُنُوبِهِ.*

From Imam Sadiq: If a believer has many sins and hasn't done much to have it washed away, then Allah would **bring sorrow** to him in this world so that it would cleanse him. If that works then so be it, if it doesn't then Allah would **bring illness** to his body to cleanse him. If that works then so be it, if it doesn't then Allah would make it **hard on him when he dying** . If that works then so be it, if not then Allah would **make it hard for him in his grave** so that when he sees Allah (in the hereafter), he would be cleansed and once he sees Allah, he would be cleansed of his sins
*Amali Saduq (A Shia book)*

### *عَسَى أَن تَكْرَهُواْ شَيْئًا وَيَجْعَلَ اللّهُ فِيهِ خَيْرًا كَثِيرًا*

it may be that you dislike a thing while Allah has placed abundant good in it.[Nisa' 19](http://quran.com/4/19)

It may be that having financial problems is good for your hereafter and maybe perhaps if you had a great life, you would have forgotten Allah!
Do get a Financial adviser, but know the best of financial adviser is Allah...truly if Allah sees it in your benefit to not grant a wish or to delay it for 2 days/years/decades then so be it!
*so maybe you are just getting cleanses for your sins or maybe its just a test, or maybe its just Allah's way to get you close to him*

Sometimes Allah tries to make you stick around by giving you constant problems.
Allah likes to bring his servants to himself:

- For some he gives them more bounties and as a result of their thanksgiving, they become closer to Allah!
- For some he gives more misfortunes and as a result of their worship to Allah they become closer to Allah!

As for non-believers, it could be many things:

- Success in this world doesn't mean success in the afterlife, in Islam the hereafter is valued more than this world.
- Sometimes Allah just simply is done with a servant and as of way of doing that is the says, " You don't want me anymore? OK! Granted! I'll give you everything you need so that you would never need to remember me again!"
- It could that this to you is just a test! I mean to see people less close to Allah get better things!

Comment: Alhamdulilla.
"Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. "Our Lord, do not impose blame upon us if we have forgotten or erred. Our Lord, and lay not upon us a burden like that which You laid upon those before us. Our Lord, and burden us not with that which we have no ability to bear. And pardon us; and forgive us; and have mercy upon us. You are our protector, so give us victory over the disbelieving people." 
Al-Quran[ 2: 286]

Comment: @AllaudeenN
If barakat is your concern, the there are many things possible, too much to pinpoint yet sins of: disrespect to Parents/kin/Quran/loss of hope or by some narrations having musical instruments in your house,etc...could be a cause of concern

Comment: Well done, @asma22, your response can be considered as a persuasive answer. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Allah does not solve your problems. Making Salah, Dua, etc.. is for your hereafter. Allah might or might not make it better for you in this life, but it is up to you.

What is causing these financial issues? Get a financial planner? If you don't have a job, get one. Save your money, work harder, etc..

Don't expect Allah to solve your worldly matters just because you make so much Dua, it doesn't work that way. The other people who don't believe in Allah are richer because probably of their hard work.

Comment: Anything you want to support your answer with?

Comment: I am a Hard Worker. I have a Good Work. I had hand full of salary. But I admit there is no Barakat in my salary. Sorry that I disagree with your answer. Because, Without Allah, nothing happens for anyone. This is the complete belief we should have. Allah may or may not grant a Dua and it is upto Allah SWT. But as a Human, we have to keep on asking Allah SWT for our needs.

Comment: @Amerrican Muslim,  what do you mean dont wait for allah to make your Dua come true, everything in this world happen by Allah's order, even if you work hard if allah does not allow it so you can get pay for your work you will never get it

Comment: @AllaudeenN Then get/speak to a financial planner on how to better manage your money, that is what they were made for. There is nothing wrong with seeking professional help if needed.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim
I approve what you are saying, but not completely: (yet I am pretty sure the asker already knows or has done that)
Furu' Kafi, Vol.5, Imam Sadiq:" Allah may increase the sustenance of the ignorant (الاحمق) person so that the wise and intelligent people would know not all things in this world can be achieved by effort or strategy." i.e. many people ( intelligent or not) without the help of a financial adviser are successful and many ( pious or pagan) the help of one are still not successful. Allah is above all